# Can you reflect geometry (not textures) in three.js?

Tags: reflection, three.js, geometry

I have found many examples of three.js reflecting images, but is at all possible to reflect lines, triangles and shapes?  I want to create a mirror pyramid that reflects lines.

For example: http://www.gus.graphics/buffer.html  >This page has lots of lines.

I want to reflect them onto a 3d shape that sits in the middle.

For example: http://www.gus.graphics/ball1.html  > This page has a mirror ball.

These are the sort of lines of code I am looking at. Not sure if it's even possible.

```
var textureCube = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube( urls );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, envMap: textureCube } ) 
shader.uniforms[ "tCube" ].value = textureCube;
```

At the moment that code above is taking in a bunch of images "urls", but as you probably know by now I want to reflect the geometry in the first link I provided.

Comment: That depends on the shape. If it is a line or plane, reflection is a simple linear operation and can be achieved with an adequate model matrix. If it is not, things get a bit more complicated and you probably need to employ a shader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at `THREE.CubeCamera`. It creates 6 cameras that render to a WebGLRenderTargetCube and then use it as envMap. An example would be:

```
//Create cube camera
var cubeCamera = new THREE.CubeCamera( 1, 100000, 128 );
scene.add( cubeCamera );

//Create material and mesh
var chromeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, envMap: cubeCamera.renderTarget } );
var car = new Mesh( carGeometry, chromeMaterial );
scene.add( car );

//Update the render target cube
car.setVisible( false );
cubeCamera.position.copy( car.position );
cubeCamera.updateCubeMap( renderer, scene );

//Render the scene
car.setVisible( true );
renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

See this: http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Cameras/CubeCamera

There are also examples usage here:

- http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_cubemap_dynamic
- http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_cubemap_dynamic2